# Регулярное выражение для вывода изменения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть значение переменной  "my name is Anton and I change the text." 
Я корректирую и отправляю "Hi my name is Antonio and I changes this text."

Получаю строки данных об корректирование текста в следующем формате...

```
[(1, 'Hi'), (0, ' my name is Anton'), (1, 'io'), (0, ' and I change'), (1, 's'), (0, ' th'), (-1, 'e'), (1, 'is'), (0, ' text.')]
```

Подскажите,как мне нужно вытянуть данные чтоб их можно было выводить в формате..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы знать, где были правки, нужно знать, где были правки. С указанными данными таких сведений нет. Как минимум нужны начальные и конечные позиции правок.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм:

Берем каждую пару число-строка.

- если число 1, то строку выводим цветом для добавленного текста (зеленым),
- если число 0, то строку выводим цветом по умолчанию (черным),
- если число -1, то строку выводим цветом для удаленного текста (красным).

С учетом вышеизложенного собираем из исходных фрагментов итоговую строку в том порядке, как идут данные. Профит.

Comment: У меня вопрос в том что нужно реализвать - "Берем каждую пару число-строка." и в массив